# Сохранять в файл по определенному количеству строк

Tags: php

Всем привет.

У меня на руках есть массив(с большим количеством элементов) вида

```
$a = array(
  'строка 1',
  'строка 2',
  'строка 3',
  'строка 4',
  .....
  'строка 500',
);
```

Мне нужно сохранять в файлы по 50 строк.
Никак не могу сделать правильно условие, чтобы каждые 50 итераций сохранять в файл и продолжать дальше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно счетчик, как советовал [[@Prikot](/users/14536/prikot)](/users/14536/prikot), а можно сразу разбить массив с помощью функции [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php). Можно не записывать посторочно каждую часть, а "склеить" с помощью [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) и разделителя "\n" или "\r\n", в зависимости от системы. В итоге, должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
$input_array = [ /* исходный массив*/ ];
$parts = array_chunk($input_array, 50);
$i = 1;
foreach($parts as $part){
  file_put_contents('data_file_'.($i++).'.txt', implode("\r\n", $part));
}
```

В итогде получите N-ное количество файлов: data_file_1.txt, data_file_2.txt и т.д., где будет по 50 строк

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, получилось.


Такой вопрос еще. А если у меня в $input_array массив из xpath, в $part->asXML();

Тогда получается, в $parts у меня многомерный массив, который сохранять нужно иначе, потому что ваш пример не получается что-то нормально там приспособить.

Comment: @drop_off, как у вас может быть массив, если asXML():

> Возвращает сформированный XML документ в виде строки используя SimpleXML элемент

Но даже, если у вас двумерный массив, то я не знаю вам нужно. Из многомерного массива, всегда [можно сделать одномерный][1].

   [1]:http://incode.pro/php/sozdaem-odnomernyj-massiv-iz-mnogomernogo.html

Comment: @Deonis, у меня вот так.
только условие нормально не знаю как сделать. там же в массиве может быть любое количество элементов. может быть больше $max, а может быть меньше.

<?php
$file = 1;
$max = 50;
$_a = $xml->xpath('//product');

foreach ($_a as $k => $v)
{
 $str .= $v->asXML();
 $count++;

 if (...)
 {
  file_put_contents('product-'.$file.'.xml', '<products>'.$str.'</products>');
  $count = 0;
  $str = '';
  $file++;
 }
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

В fopen добавь флаг `а` или `а+`

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");  
$stringData = "New Stuff 1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);  
$stringData = "New Stuff 2\n";  
fwrite($fh, $stringData);  
fclose($fh);
```

P.S. Покажи код.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте переменную-счетчик, в цикле инкрементируйте (var++) эту переменную. Добавьте условие, если счетчик равен 50, то производим запись и обнуляем переменную-счетчик.